# Best practice: Where to install Linux packages

Tags: linux, opensuse, compile, proftpd

Where is the best path to install all files of package when compiling?

For example - I want to install ProFTPd, so there's an option

```
--prefix=/usr/local/proftpd
```

, which means, that all files after compilation (including binary and configuration files) will be stored here. As you know, all packages, which are installed via package system (like zypper on SuSE or apt on Ubuntu) usually stores its configuration files in /etc/ and binary files in /sbin/ and also stores a link in my $PATH, so i can run in just by typing proftpd (without /sbin).

The huge advantage of packages installed via package system, i think, is easy uninstall process. I'd like to be able to uninstall compiled packages also easy.

I think i could be able to create some batch file, which I'll be able to use like this:

```
uninstall --package=proftpd
```

And my script will find all proftpd files in usuall paths (/etc, /sbin) and remove it using rm.

Is there any best practices, where to store all these files, or are there any (dis)advantages of my first example (--prefix=/usr/local/proftpd)?

I really don't think, that it's nice to have 2 paths with configuration files and binary files, but maybe I'm misunderstanding the basic principals of Linux... :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html)

The distro gets `/usr`, you get `/usr/local`, ISVs get `/opt`.

Comment: Yeah, I got your point, but are there (dis)advantages of installing into /usr instead of /sbin? Like permissions (security) or links?

Comment: If you install local packages local to your machine into /usr/local then you can backup those local packages which you may not do for /sbin. And yes, you are failing to understand basic principles of file systems; for example, why wouldn't you just store every file in one directory?

Comment: One disadvantage in installing under /sbin -some linux distros expect the bare minimum to start a system in /bin, /sbin and /lib, and then all the rest of the commands under /usr/bin, /usr/sbin and /usr/lib. Some distros will create a very small partition to store the stuff under /, and then a much larger partition to store the stuff under /usr. So check the space available under /sbin -it might be limited.

Answer (score 4):

The best places to install packages on your machine are `/usr/local` if you have admin rights and want everyone to use your program, or `$HOME` if you want to just make a copy for yourself.

Normally you'd set the prefix as `--prefix=/usr/local` so that the application files are stored in `/usr/local/bin` settings in `/usr/local/etc` and so on.

The advantage of using these standard places is ...well, basically that they are standard. People know where to look for the files. For example, `/usr/local/bin` is almost always in everybody's `$PATH`, so you won't have to fiddle with the `$PATH` variable to get people to run it. Similarly, libraries are found by checking `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but `/usr/local/lib` is usually checked by default so you don't need to add it manually, and so on.

Regarding uninstalling: Once you have run configure and built the program, then `make install` will install it for you, and `make uninstall` will remove the files automatically.

Comment: You're right with make uninstall, but afaik sometimes it's not available in the package.

Comment: True. I like the checkinstall idea mentioned below. I'm going to try that next time I install something on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the best approach is probably to create a package that you can install.

Many applications come with the necessary files to create RPM or DEB packages. If they don't, there are tools to create packages automatically, for example [checkinstall](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/).

`checkinstall` will monitor the operations of `make install`, and redirect the installed files to create a DEB or RPM package from them. That way, you get a regular package that is integrated with your other packages.

There are some caveats (you will not get dependencies, and some very complicated install scripts may fail), but usually it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Best practise is to follow the [Linux Standard Base](http://ldn.linuxfoundation.org/lsb/lsb4-resource-page#Specification), particularly the [filesystem hierarchy standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).